# Micrsoft Graph API - How to get list of inactive users

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

Using the Graph API how do i get a list of inactive users.

I tried this:

Which gets the active users but what about inactive users:

```
var graphClient = MicrosoftGraph.GetGraphClient(tenantId, clientId);
       
var users = await graphClient.Users
.Request()
.Select("displayName,signInActivity")
.GetAsync();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users endpoint for beta Graph API returns property `signInActivity` on `select` and gets the last signed-in date of the sign-in for a given user.

You can use `lastSignInDateTime` field on signInActivity resource to calculate the last time a user signed in to the directory with an interactive authentication method.

You need to define by yourself what means that user is **inactive** in the case of your environment.

In many organizations, the delta for inactive user accounts is between 90 and 180 days.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?select=displayName,signInActivity&filter=signInActivity/lastSignInDateTime le 2019-06-01T00:00:00Z
```

Code

```
var inactiveDate = DateTime.Now.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(90)).ToString("u").Replace(" ","T");
var inactiveUsers = await graphClient.Users
.Request()
.Select("displayName,signInActivity")
.Filter($"signInActivity/lastSignInDateTime le {inactiveDate}")
.GetAsync();
```

Microsoft Graph Beta .NET Client [Library](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-beta-sdk-dotnet) is required.

Resources:

[SignInActivity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/signinactivity?view=graph-rest-beta)

Comment: Hi thanks for the given answer, im sure its correct, its just im getting an error:

      Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: Request_UnsupportedQuery
      Message: Property 'lastSignInDateTime' does not exist as a declared property or 
      extension property.

Not sure what this means, but is it to do with the version im using?

Comment: I guess that you are using SDK v1.0 but you need SDK beta because signInActivity is available only for beta endpoint. https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-beta-sdk-dotnet